# Error copying file on xampp installing in ubuntu

Tags: lamp, xampp

I want to try install `xampp` on Ubuntu 14.04, I download  `xampp-linux-x64-5.6.15-1-installer.run`
and try to run it with `sudo` ,but in between of unpacking it getting error .

[image]

I lookup at path `/opt/lamp` some files getting copy but installation not getting complete, I try to see log in install duration with `tail -f /usr/log/syslog` but nothing reported. where is the problem?

**update**
according to comment I try `df -h` to see free space of my disk

[image]

Comment: Do you have enough space on your hard-drive?

Comment: You can check that by typing `df -h`

Comment: I agree: probably lack of space. If you want to use a webserver please use own our native version. It is pre-configured, designed to be -secure-  and well documented and we can help you with it if you have question (where xampp lacks in -all- of these points). It is as easy as typing `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^`.

Comment: @Raphael yes, I update my question with screenshot of df -h

Comment: Please post text files and program output listings as text, not as images (see [How do I save terminal output to a file?](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814)).